# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: You're using the staticfiles app without having set the STATIC_ROOT setting to a filesystem path

Tags: python, django, heroku, deploy

Estou tentando adicionar a minha aplicação ao heroku, para que esteja disponível na web. Mas na hora de fazer o deploy recebo a seguinte mensagem de erro:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: You're using the staticfiles app without having set the STATIC_ROOT setting to a filesystem path.

Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.
```

Já fiz diversas procuras na internet sobre essa mensagem de erro, ja alterei varias vezes o `STATIC_ROOT` , testei também com `STATIC_URL` mas nada resolve meu problema.

Segue abaixo o trecho de código do settings.py responsável pelo static.

```
if os.getcwd() == '/app':
   import dj_database_url
   DATABASES ={
    'default': dj_database_url.config(default='postgres://localhost')
   }

  #Honra o cabeçalho 'X-Forwarded-Proto' para request.is_secure()
  SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

  #Cabeçalho para permitir todos os hosts
  ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

  #Configurações de recursos estáticos
  BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

  STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'

  STATICFILES_DIRS = (
     os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
  )
```

Trecho do código do wsgi.py

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'learning_log.settings')

application = Cling(get_wsgi_application())
```

E a organização dos arquivos e pasta está disposta nessa maneira:

```
-learning_log
     ---learning_log
     -----settings.py
     -----wsgi.py
     -----static
     --------placeholder.txt (.txt apenas para não deixar o static vazio)
```

Answer (score -1):

Tenta adicionar o "/" antes do nome, assim por exemplo:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

Caso seja a versão mais recente do Django use

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'staticfiles'
```

E caso tenha arquivos estáticos dentro de uma app

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'app1/static'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'app2/static')
]
```